# Logging into Local Statusnet instance on Apache causes browser to download a file

Tags: apache-2.2

I've installed statusnet 0.9.1 on a Windows Server via the WAMP stack and on the whole it seems to be fine.

However, when logging in using IE7 or Chrome the browers invoke a file download, i.e. the File Download dialog is displayed.
In IE7 the file is called notice with the content below (some parts starred out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <ShortName>Mumble Notice Search</ShortName>
    <Contact>david.carson@*****.com</Contact>
    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://voice.*****.com/mumble/search/notice?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
    <Image height="16" width="16" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">http://voice.*****.com/mumble/favicon.ico</Image>
    <Image height="50" width="50" type="image/png">http://voice.******.com/mumble/theme/cloudy/logo.png</Image>
    <AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
    <Language>en_GB</Language>
    <OutputEncoding>UTF-8</OutputEncoding>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

In Chrome (Linux and Windows!) the file is called people and contains similar XML.

This is not an issue when logging in using FireFox.

This is obviously a configuration issue but I'm not having much luck tracking it down. I tested the previous version of Statusnet on an Ubuntu Server VM on our network and it worked fine for months.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

That's really interesting! That's an OpenSearch XML document (see http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_description_document), and it's included as  in the HTML code.

I haven't seen this issue on a Windows server before, though. Maybe you could register the Open Search document type with the server?

Comment: Thanks Evan - although I'm unsure how to do this :-( 
I'll Google around a bit bit if you have any pointers then please let me know.

Comment: For the time being I've made a quick modification to the showHead function in lib/action.php, basically commented out the call to showOpenSearch().

Not ideal but at least it will let use move on until I get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Status.net 0.9.1 on Ubuntu Server 9.10 and it's showing the same behaviour.

Comment: I've worked around the problem (see my response to Evans answer) but still not 100% sure how to fix it properly. For our purposes we don't need this functionality at the moment but this could change.